# Ayuda con una consulta SQL, sumas

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy realizando un SQL en la cual quiero sumar cuyo producto sea similar es decir.

Tengo mi sql, se los adjunto.

```
select distinct cat.Nombre as Categoria, pro2.Nombre as Producto, InventarioInicial, ocd.CostoUnitario
from Inventario as inv2
inner join (
        select
        inv.ProductoID,
        pro.Nombre,
        count(inv.ProductoID) as InventarioInicial
        from Inventario as inv
        inner join Productos as pro on pro.ID = inv.ProductoID
        where inv.Consumido <> 1
        group by pro.Nombre, inv.ProductoID

        ) as c2 on c2.ProductoID = inv2.ProductoID
inner join Productos as pro2 on pro2.ID = inv2.ProductoID
inner join Categorias as cat on cat.ID = pro2.CategoriaID
left join OrdenDeCompraDetalles as ocd on ocd.ProductoID = pro2.ID
```

Este es el resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera sumar los productos similares, es decir el campo **CostoUnitario**
Cuyos Nombre de Producto sea igual, para no tener duplicados los productos con diferente costo unitario. 
Espero que me ayuden o asesoren.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agrupar los campos con un `GROUP BY` y los campos que sean valores numericos los sumas con un `SUM` , Asi

```
select distinct 
    cat.Nombre as Categoria, 
    pro2.Nombre as Producto, 
    SUM(InventarioInicial) as InventarioInicial, 
    SUM(ocd.CostoUnitario) as CostoUnitario
from Inventario as inv2
inner join (
        select
        inv.ProductoID,
        pro.Nombre,
        count(inv.ProductoID) as InventarioInicial
        from Inventario as inv
        inner join Productos as pro on pro.ID = inv.ProductoID
        where inv.Consumido <> 1
        group by pro.Nombre, inv.ProductoID

        ) as c2 on c2.ProductoID = inv2.ProductoID
inner join Productos as pro2 on pro2.ID = inv2.ProductoID
inner join Categorias as cat on cat.ID = pro2.CategoriaID
left join OrdenDeCompraDetalles as ocd on ocd.ProductoID = pro2.ID
GROUP BY cat.Nombre,pro2.Nombre
```

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices, solo agregaría que el `distinct` es innecesario cuando usas un `group by`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho exactamente es innecesario pero eso lo dicide el, yo en mi caso lo utilizo solo para verificar que no existan datos repetidos