# Contar los articulos pedidos

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas, una es de `articulos` y la otra es para guardar la informacion de cuando se *compro* un *articulo*, la *cantidad comprada*, la *fecha* y al *precio* que se compro en ese momento. (Se usa asi para luego hacer un informe de cuanta ganancia hubo segun la fecha en que se compró).

Entonces cada *articulo* puede tener `stocks diferentes`.

Las tablas quedan así:

[image: imagen]

Tengo esta consulta:
`

```
SELECT articulos.id, articulos.nombre,articulos.stock_existente,stock_pedido AS stock, "
                    + "articulos.precio_venta, articulos.tipo FROM articulos "
                    + "LEFT JOIN art_stock ON art_stock.producto_id = articulos.id "
                    + "WHERE articulos.state= 'ACTIVO'";
```

Pero el problema es que me muestra datos repetidos, es decir si hay un *articulo* que tuvo 2 compras en periodos diferentes, con valores distintos, me va a aparecer dos veces.

Yo lo que quiero es que me aparezca **1 vez cada articulo** , y **sumado** la **cantidad de veces** que se pidio.

Comment: ¿Conocés las [funciones de agregación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)?

Comment: Hay muchas preguntas en el sitio acerca de procesar duplicados, que una búsqueda sencilla como "sumar duplicados", presenta respuestas que pueden utilizadas. Voy a votar esta pregunta como duplicada, puesto que no presenta una significativa diferencia en relación a las demás.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo sumar registros que contengan valores duplicados?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/332561/c%c3%b3mo-sumar-registros-que-contengan-valores-duplicados). O tal vez [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179898/ayuda-con-una-consulta-sql-sumas)?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que buscas es una inquietud bastante clásica, como transformar un grupo de `n` filas de una tabla en una sola. Puede haber varios criterios según la necesidad, quiero la primer fila, la última, el de cierta fecha, o bien, como dices: **y sumado la cantidad de veces que se pidió**, una agrupación de filas y la aplicación de una función de agregación como `SUM()`:

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.nombre,
       a.stock_existente,
       IFNULL(SUM(s.stock_pedido), 0) AS stock
       a.precio_venta, 
       a.tipo 
       FROM articulos a
       LEFT JOIN art_stock s
            ON s.producto_id = a.id
       WHERE a.state = 'ACTIVO'
       GROUP BY
             a.id, 
             a.nombre,
             a.stock_existente,
             a.precio_venta, 
             a.tipo
```

Comentarios:

- Trabajamos con alias de tablas para hacer más corta la escritura: `FROM articulos a`
- La idea es agrupar por todas las columnas de `articulos` y sumar `stock_pedido`, debes indicar todas las columnas del `SELECT` en el `GROUP BY`, excepto las que participan en funciones de agregación.
- El `ISNULL()` es para indicar un 0 en caso que no haya filas coincidentes en `art_stock`